# converting Javascript dates from date value to date obj

Tags: javascript

I have problem in converting dates values to date objects:

```
const date = 1614769200;
const date = new Date(1614769200); //this date shows up in Mon Jan 19 1970
```

Comment: Try and multiply it by `1000`.

Comment: What’s the problem you’re having? What do you expect that date to be?

Comment: One mistake is that the ``date`` is already been declared. You cannot declare the same variable or constant more than once. Also, the value of a constant cannot be changed, and you are trying to change the value of the contact in the second statement.

Comment: @NotABot yes the deceleration was false in my post, but my problem was with converting millisecond date, now it's is solved by nicks solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript uses **milliseconds** for numeric values of dates.

You will need to multiply the value by `1000`.

```js
const date = 1614769200;
const dateObj = new Date(date * 1000); //Wed Mar 03 2021
console.log(dateObj);
```